# How do use MySql Regex inside locate?

Tags: mysql, regex, locate

If I try to use  Regex inside locate it fails

```
Select Locate(FieldA regexp '[a-z][A-Z][a-z]',Binary FieldA) from  PatternTester
```

as per http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/403c36/2.

If I search for the explicit letter pattern it locates it correctly:

```
Select Locate('lC',Binary FieldA) from  PatternTester
```

as per http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/403c36/6

Is there something I need to do to make locate 'obey' Regex or will it simply not?

Comment: [REGEXP_INSTR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr)

Comment: @Akina My MySql Version 5.6.47 says the command does not exist.

Comment: There is no suitable function in such ancient version.

Comment: You are checking to see of a string has _any_ camelcase in it?  Or do you necessarily need to "locate" it, also?

Comment: @Rick James. I actually want to extract it. I found a way to do so if I look for a specific pattern eg `lC` with a few embedded `substring_index` statements which included '`Binary` but now the trick would be to replace the explcit pattern with a regex instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mysql document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) says, `LOCATE()` will `returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string st`, so it will not take any regex as input argument.

Also from checking your fiddle reference, you don't have [REGEX_INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr) in this version!